# How can I prevent log growth in SQL Server when update millions of records, not insert

Tags: sql-server, logfile

I have an update query in SQL Server that needs to update 50 million records, but when I execute this query, my database log file grows to 100GB and stops because of disk full.

How can I prevent log file from growing?

Comment: May be you can try, changing Recovery model from "Full" to "SImple"

Comment: @marc_s That question you mark is insert query and my question is about update and thoes are diffrent.

Comment: The ultimate *reason* behind it is the **same** - you're not properly doing transaction log backups, and therefore your disk fills up. Learn about proper SQL Server DBA tasks - and you'll be able to fix both your `INSERT` and your `UPDATE` "problem"

Comment: @marc_s I fount a proper solution and put it as an answer to this question. I test it and it is ok. May be it is not the best way, but in the end saved my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that solve my problem, but i do not sure that it is the best or optimized way. The solution is this: split your update recordes to lower count batch. I use batch with 10000 records with a wile loop.

```
    DECLARE @batchNum int; set @batchNum= 10000;
    DECLARE @ind int; select @ind=MIN(Isn_Num) from PURCHASE_INVOICE_D07F088L1;      
    DECLARE @maxind int; select @maxind=max(Isn_Num) from PURCHASE_INVOICE_D07F088L1; 

    while @ind<=@maxind
    begin
    --update query

        set @ind=@ind+@batchNum 
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  You can be sure that the [recovery model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx) for the database is set to "SIMPLE".  Then you can do the update in batches.

Even with the SIMPLE recovery model, the updates will still be logged.  However, the log records will be deleted after every transaction.